# What is this bayonet I found in the ground while working under a house?

Tags: identification, weapons

It's got some markings including a WD with a arrow above it, below that a Crown with 45 under it and then a E. And right by the hilt is a X. On the other side there is VI. And below that is 1.95...it had a sheath and stuff. But I don't know anything about these.

Comment: Including an image would improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: If it was buried a general location might be useful as well. you can use the [edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/74373/edit) function to add photos and updated information (measurements are always helpful as well).

Answer (score 1):

At this point the markings mentioned give us some basic information to begin researching. The 'WD with a arrow above it' identify this as an item manufactured for the UK [War Department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Department_(United_Kingdom)). A little more googling leads to another identification site that mentions specs on a similar item at the [civilWarTalk forum](https://civilwartalk.com/threads/p1853-enfield-bayonet-marking.144778/):

> The "Broad Arrow/WD" are War Department ownership markings. The
> "Crown/E/35" indicates the bayonet was made at the Enfield Armory and
> inspected by Inspector #35.

So looks like a UK Enfield bayonet. Similar specs as your item, perhaps inspector #45. Can do more in depth research on model when updates such as images and dimensions posted.